# Using ‘split’ with delimiter with multiple uses

Tags: perl, delimiter

So I have a csv file on a movie database, and I am reading that into an array. I need to split each part of the array into another array, or at least have it accessible to manipulate.

Here is an example of the csv file:

```
adult,belongs_to_collection,budget,genres,homepage,id,imdb_id,original_language,original_title,overview,popularity,poster_path,production_companies,production_countries,release_date,revenue,runtime,spoken_languages,status,tagline,title,video,vote_average,vote_count
```

An example of an actual tuple

```
False,"{'id': 10194, 'name': 'Toy Story Collection', 'poster_path': '/7G9915LfUQ2lVfwMEEhDsn3kT4B.jpg', 'backdrop_path': '/9FBwqcd9IRruEDUrTdcaafOMKUq.jpg'}",30000000,"[{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}]",http://toystory.disney.com/toy-story,862,tt0114709,en,Toy Story,"Led by Woody, Andy's toys live happily in his room until Andy's birthday brings Buzz Lightyear onto the scene. Afraid of losing his place in Andy's heart, Woody plots against Buzz. But when circumstances separate Buzz and Woody from their owner, the duo eventually learns to put aside their differences.",21.946943,/rhIRbceoE9lR4veEXuwCC2wARtG.jpg,"[{'name': 'Pixar Animation Studios', 'id': 3}]","[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",1995-10-30,373554033,81.0,"[{'iso_639_1': 'en', 'name': 'English'}]",Released,,Toy Story,False,7.7,5415
```

Here is my code:

```
open (NAMEFILE, "movies_metadata.csv");
my @topgrossmovie = <NAMEFILE>;
close NAMEFILE;

foreach $x ( @topgrossmovie ) {
    my ($adult,$belongs_to_collection,$budget,$genres,$homepage,$id,$imdb_id,$original_language,$original_title,$overview,$popularity,$poster_path,$production_companies,$production_countries,$release_date,$revenue,$runtime,$spoken_languages,$status,$tagline,$title,$video,$vote_average,$vote_count) = split /,/, $x;
}
```

Because of their being a comma `,` within tuples makes it extremely difficult.

Comment: Using a [proper CSV parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS) would be a good start

Comment: Why not use a real database instead of CSV?

Comment: The delimiters use in this format are: comma, apostrophe, double-quote, square bracket, curly bracket and colon. Have you considered the difficulty when escaping those characters when they actually need to appear in the values? The design decision to use CSV is going to cause you pain. Either use a real database (as said above), or consider using a format like XML which would cope better with this kind of hierarchical data.

Comment: @Richard: Those aren't "delimiters": they're just punctuation characters.

Comment: @Borodin in order to extract the data from that line of CSV, all of those characters would need to be used, since they delimit different parts of the data, so they *are* [delimiters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter).

Comment: @Richardissimo, Re "*in order to extract the data from that line of CSV,  all of those characters would need to be used*", No. This is standard CSV. (`sep_char` is `,` and `quote_char` is `"`. The sample is insufficient to determine `escape_char`.) Square brackets are no more special than `a`, for example. Extracting data from the some of the fields after they've been extracted from the CSV is another matter.

Comment: @Richardissimo The `"` protect the punctuation inside fields, which are correctly delimited by `,`.  Then it's something JSON-like  in the fields

Comment: The real bad decision is the choice to use something JSON-like instead of JSON. (`False` is not a valid JSON value, and `'id'` is not a valid object key literal.) That means you'll have to write your own parser instead of being able to take advantage of an existing parser.

Comment: @ikegami  I think by "tuple" they mean the row in the file so `False` is just a CSV field.  The problem in the json-look-alike is the single quotes `'` instead of `"` (there may be more problems).  So perhaps it's "relaxed json".  A bad choice I agree

Comment: @zdim, Oops, yes, `False` isn't in the JSON-like string. That means the wrong quotes might be the only deviation from the JSON, in which case the OP could use JSON:PP with `->allow_singlequote(1)`.

Comment: @ikegami I didn't know that JSON::PP had that option. That's good to know!

Comment: @RichardPointing Was the CSV file supplied to you, or did you construct it yourself from things like the JSON information?

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Use an existing parser such as [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS).

If you need to extract data from the JSON-like strings (once you've extracted them from the CSV), you might be able to take advantage of [JSON::PP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::PP) with `->allow_singlequote(1)`. (Note that the faster [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::XS) doesn't support that option.)